# mongoose connection in development

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, connection

I've come across the statement that a mongoose connection should not have multiple connections and stay open as long as the application is running, so a single blocking operation cannot freeze up the node.js application. That seems reasonable, however in production - if I have to test my backend, then I'm rerunning my files all the time with node. Each time opening a new connection without closing it. This has resulted in 100 connections from my laptop to my cloud mongodb, which is the cap for it to be operational.

In terms of code - **should I open and close a connection every time I run a query? If so, damn. If not, how?**

I am unsure about pretty much everything at this point, so if my question is vague I apoligize.

Answer (score 1):

Use ***mongoose.disconnect()*** function

it disconnects all connections.

Check this [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-disconnect)